# Proving a polynomial is injective on restricted domain

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the following function is injective 
$ f:[2,\infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R : x \mapsto x^2 -4x + 5 $

I've shown that the range is $[1,\infty)$ by $f(2+\sqrt{c-1} )=c$
I know that to show injectivity I need to show $x_{1}\not= x_{2} \implies f(x_{1}) \not= f(x_{2})$. But this leads me to $(x_{1})^2-4(x_{1})=(x_{2})^2-4(x_{2})$. What reasoning can I give for those to be equal?

Comment: Subscripts: $x_{1}$ is done by `x_{1}`

Comment: Thank, I've fixed that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good: suppose $c\ge1$; then
$$
x^2-4x+5=c
$$
leads to
$$
x=2-\sqrt{c-1}\qquad\text{or}\qquad x=2+\sqrt{c-1}
$$
and there is a *unique* solution in $[2,\infty)$.

So you have computed the inverse function from $[1,\infty)$ to $[2,\infty)$. Hence the given function is injective.

The other method can be used as well. Suppose $2\le x_1\le x_2$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Then
$$
x_2^2-4x_2+5=x_1^2-4x_1+5
$$
so
$$
(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1)-4(x_2-x_1)=0
$$
which becomes
$$
(x_2-x_1)(x_2+x_1-4)=0
$$
Hence either
$$
x_2+x_1=4
$$
which implies $x_1=x_2=2$, or
$$
x_2-x_1=0
$$
which implies $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer is extremely clear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_1,x_2\in [2,+\infty) $ such that

$x_1\neq x_2$ and $f (x_1)=f (x_2) $.

then by Rolle's  Theorem

$\exists c\in (x_1,x_2) :$
$$f'(c)=0=2c-4$$

which is in contradiction with $c>2$.

$f $ is injective.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the maximum point of your parabola, and then you can check if your domain is on one side of the maximum, and thus injective. So just calculate,

$$ \frac{df}{dx} = 0, $$

since you know that $f'$ is a straight line it will differ from zero everywhere except at the maxima and thus the restriction to the left or right side will be monotonic and thus injective.

Answer (score 0):

$$f (x_1)=f (x_2)\implies $$

$$x_1^2-4x_1=x_2^2-4x_2 \implies$$

$$x_1^2-x_2^2=4 (x_1-x_2)\implies$$

$$(x_1-x_2)(x_1+x_2-4)=0$$
but
$$x_1>x_2\geq 2$$ then
$$x_1+x_2>2x_2\geq 4$$
or
$$x_1+x_2-4>0$$
thus
$$x_1=x_2$$.